# Is there evidence that Mauthausen Concentration Camp commander Franz Ziereis’s son shot prisoners of the camp?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, austria, concentration-camps

In the Spanish film the photographer of Mauthausen there is a scene of a party held to celebrate the birthday of the son of Mauthausen Concentration Camp commander (Franz Ziereis).

In the scene the boy shoots a prisoner with a pistol received as a gift. Researching the accuracy of this, I encountered some mention of the child shooting prisoners from his front porch, but nothing else. [remember.org](https://remember.org/camps/mauthausen/mau-commandant)
Does anyone know further details of on this s topic? Also, it would be of some interest to me, how young Ziereis’s adult life turned out.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) For example does [remember.org](https://remember.org/camps/mauthausen/mau-commandant) answer the question?

Comment: I am feeling uncomfortable with this question, at least as far as it enquires about the child involved. According to today's standards, especially UNICEF's [Paris Principles](https://www.unicef.org/mali/media/1561/file/ParisPrinciples.pdf), the child would be considered to be "primarily [a] victim...; not only [a] perpetrator." Accordingly, the text states: "It is essential for the protection of children and their families that personal information relating to violations of children’s rights including...use by...armed groups be treated as confidential." (p. 13)

Comment: Sure, that child would now be an old man. But my feeling is that at the time, he should have had a right to be forgiven, and a right to be forgotten by the public, and that should hold on until today.

Comment: @jveason: This *may* be of help: The holdings of the US National Archives include "Copy of an Intelligence Report by the 511th CIC Detachment dated May 30, 1945. Entitled "A 12 Year Old Nazi," it describes the apprehension and interrogation of [...], the son of Franz Ziereis, Commandant of Mauthausen." A quick internet search indicates that the younger Ziereis is likely deceased at this time. In light of the young age of the person inquired about at the time of relevant events, I concur with ccprog's reservations about rolling out the case here.

Comment: A bit more info. According to End of a Berlin Diary : 1944-1947  by William L. Shirer… “ Which reminds me of another item in the local press. It tells of the testimony of a fifteen-year-old German lad, the son of the former SS commander of the Mauthausen concentration camp. Questioned about his father, the boy said: “For my birthday, my father put forty inmates at my disposal to teach me how to shoot. I took shots at them until they were all lying around dead. Otherwise, I have nothing else to report about my father.”